# Bind the JSON data to smart table from 2 different files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to populate the smart table with 2 different JSON files. Used the property Observable.forkjoin() but it will not bind. How can I do it?
Please help me

service.ts

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
@Injectable()
export class SmartTablesService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    
        }
        
        smartTableData = [];
//data/article.json
loadData() {
  console.log('loadData');
  Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:8000/medical'),
  this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:8000/cost'))
  .subscribe((data) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              
              var contactData = [];
              $.each(data.map(res => res.json()), function (key, value) {
      //alert(data);
                //  alert(value.year);
              var tempData = value;
              alert(tempData.year);


                

                  contactData.push(tempData);
              });
              //alert(tempData.year);
              this.smartTableData = contactData;
          }, 1000);
      });
}
getData(): Promise<any> {
  console.log("Promise");
  this.loadData();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(this.smartTableData);
          resolve(this.smartTableData);
      }, 3000);
  });
}
}
```

medical

```html
[
 {
        "year": 2013,  
        "doctor": "Dr. Smith", 
        "illness": "Flu", 
        "apptdate": "3/12/2013",
  "details":"Patient had flu for 5 days. No medicines prescribed"
 },
 {
        "year": 2014,  
        "doctor": "Dr. ram", 
        "illness": "fever", 
        "apptdate": "31/12/2013",
  "details":"Patient had flu for 5 days. No medicines prescribed"
 }
]
```

cost

```html
[
 {
        "year": 2013,  
        "cost": 100
 },
 {
        "year": 2014,  
        "cost": 300
 }
]
```

How can I bind these two dates to the smart table? When I run using npm it displays the number of rows in the file. But will not displays the content in the specified column .. so please help me
[image]